# How to create ebook DRM reader and distribution platform?

Tags: java, .net, encryption, drm

My company has decided to develop ebook DRM platform. 
The platform does not have to be perfectly safe, but should be comparable to existing DRM platform.
Software can be written in .NET or Java, both client and server-side.

I am pretty much at dark on how I should approach this project and how DRM software really works.
Any good tip on where to start appreciated.

Comment: Any and all DRM sucks (and yes, that's not helping and I'm sorry - but it doesn't change that fact)

Comment: not only does DRM suck, it's a bad decision business wise, as it will not be accepted by the customer in the long run.
And it's somewhat bizarre, you're on a platform dedicated to freely exchange knowledge and advice, asking about a technology to hinder exactly that .. from the POV of these "intellectual property"
guys this is a server/cluster full of pathetic losers that are to dumb to make a bug out of it .. think about it for a minute.

Comment: People can and will get around *any* DRM. All it will do is encourage piracy and annoy your users. Think about it: DRM only affects the people that legally payed for it; pirates don't deal with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your company is developing a brand-new product in a field they're unfamiliar with, they need *someone* with some modicum of knowledge about that field.

If they just decided "hey, ebooks are hot stuff, let's create something for them", then stuck you in charge, the product is doomed to failure. Run.

Comment: I like that the questioner accepted this answer :)